# How do I "preserve" an entity when changing its parent in the DOM?

Tags: aframe

I have a "variable assignment" component that looks like the following (the blue diamond with the yellow sphere attached):

`http://i.imgur.com/nJotPgW.gif` (unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to inline the image)

Here the yellow sphere that things can snap into is created in the initialization of the variable assignment component like so

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('variable-assignment', {
  schema: {
    grabbable: {default: true}
  },
  init: function () {
    this.el.innerHTML = `
    <a-sphere
    snap-site="controller:#right-hand"
    radius=".1"
    color="yellow"
    material="transparent:true; opacity:.5;"
    position=".22 0 0">
    </a-sphere>
    `;
    this.label = 'x';
    this.el.setAttribute('geometry', {
      primitive: 'octahedron',
      radius: .1,
      color: 'blue'
    });
    ...
```

The `snap-site` component has code that detects a collision with the red sphere and then makes it a child element. So the DOM looks something like this before the collision.

```
<a-sphere color=red></a-sphere>
<a-entity variable-assignment>
    <a-sphere snap-site>
    <a-sphere>
</a-entity>
```

and after

```
<a-entity variable-assignment>
    <a-sphere snap-site>
        <a-sphere color=red></a-sphere>
    <a-sphere>
</a-entity>
```

The problem is when I want to move the entity with variable-assignment inside another DOM element using `appendChild` the initialization function for the variable-assignment called again the innerHTML is reset. So for example if we have

```
<a-entity container></a-entity>
<a-entity variable-assignment>
    <a-sphere snap-site>
        <a-sphere color=red></a-sphere>
    <a-sphere>
</a-entity>
```

And we want to move variable-assignment into container using something like `containerElement.appendChild(variableAssignmentEntity)` the inner red sphere gets removed

```
<a-entity container>
    <a-entity variable-assignment>
        <a-sphere snap-site>
        <a-sphere>
    </a-entity>
</a-entity>
```

As a work around/hack I was thinking about using a flag of some sort to see if initialize had already been called before for the element/entity the component was a property of and then not run the initialization code, something like

```
  init: function () {
    if (this.el.getAttribute('initialized')) {
        return;
    } 
    this.el.setAttribute('initialized', true);
    ...
```

but this seems like a bad way to do it and also looking into the A-Frame source it seems appendChild causes all components to be removed then added again so it doesn't actually work either or at least causes other things to break.

Is there a good way to do this or is there a different way to define the variable-assignment component so the yellow sphere snap-site component isn't a child set in the initialization?

Answer (score 2):

You're correct that `appendChild` causes components to be re-initialized, and might not work as expected. Here are a couple alternatives:

1. After removing the element, call `el = el.cloneNode()` to make a clean copy and append that, instead.
2. Don't actually make the sphere a child of your `variable-assignment` component, but instead just have the 'parent' component update the position/rotation of the child in the `tick()` function.
3. Use the underlying three.js API to pass around the [THREE.Object3D](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Object3D), without actually changing the parent of any elements.

An example of (3):

```
var mesh = el.getObject3D('mesh)';
el.removeObject3D('mesh');
otherEl.setObject3D('mesh', mesh);
```

Comment: Thanks @Don!  I'm out of town at the moment, but will try some of these when I get home and update the question with what worked best for me.

Comment: You can also use THREE.SceneUtils.attach to change parent while preserving world-space transforms.